# Microsoft PowerAutomate Flow Response ID

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I'm using the template 'Send an email to responder when response submitted in Microsoft Forms'.

So when an entry is made in Forms, the data is written to a List, and the responder receives an email with some confirmation information.

**It all works as expected, except for when I want to include the ID of the request.**

I have a column called ID in my List, which gets auto-generated for each entry made (this is standard functionality, I haven't created this).

Back to my flow; when I add the Dynamic Content of "Response ID" (which seems to be the only "ID" available) it isn't quite right.

For example, I've just entered a test record. It was assigned ID = 71 in List. But when the Flow email was triggered, the Response ID included in the body of the email was = 66.

Screenshot of data in my List:

[image: Microsoft List]

Screenshot of email received:

[image: Email Received]

Answer (score 0):

The response id is the id of the response to the Microsoft form.
If you want to save the response to SharePoint List, you could use create item action.Then you could get the new list item.

My test flow for your reference:
[image]
[image]

Test result:
[image]
[image]

**Updated:**
[image]

Comment: I can't see where your 'new item id' gets set in the above screenshots.

Comment: After you use the create item action, it will return many attributes of the created item, including ID, you can use it directly in the following actions.